# How is the damage reduction calculated from armor/mr?

Tags: league-of-legends

For example, if your champion has 200 magic resistance / armor and your enemy has some crazy AP/AD damage that can be dealt with one single spell/attack, say 800 damage at once...

Considering the enemy doesn't have any magic/armor penetration (not even MPen/APen runes), how much damage would your champion receive?

Comment: I don't know much about Leagu but the other answer doesnt seem to cover magic resistance. Maybe I'm mistaken though

Comment: Armor and Magic Resistance use the same formula. Despite the unexpected duplicate post notification, I'm glad that I asked, as I would never find it unless I'm using the "diminishing returns" words.

Comment: Also, another thing to consider, this makes my question a tl;dr version of the other post. So instead of deleting this, I'll leave it in case people don't want the long-story version, but aside from that, it's still really clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to League of Legends wikia, both [armor](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Armor) and [magic resistance](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_resistance) "*damage multiplier*" is calculated with the following formula (replace mr with armor the same):

if enemy MR is *greater or equal to 0* (**MR >= 0**) calculation is like below;

> 100 / (MR+100)

which means;

> for 100 magic resistance → × 0.5 incoming magic damage (50% reduction)

so for a single spell with magic damage of 800 will deal 400 damage (considering your have no magic penetration).

if enemy MR is *less than 0* (**MR < 0**) calculation is like below;

2 − (100 / (100-MR))

which means;

> for −25 magic resistance → × 1.2 incoming magic damage (20% increase)

so for a single spell with magic damage of 800 will deal 960 damage (considering your have no magic penetration).